# Private inheritance and ADL swap

Tags: c++

I have a type `Base` which is privately inherited from by `Derived`. `Derived` does not add any new member variables.

Now what's the correct way to write a swap for `Derived`? We can't assume `Base` has a member `swap`, so I think perhaps:

```
class Derived : private Base {
public:
    void swap(Derived& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(*this), static_cast<Base&>(other));
    }
};
```

Does this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this work correctly?

With the call `d1.swap(d2)`, yes.

But if the user tries to write:

```
using std::swap;
swap(d1, d2);
```

That will not call `swap(Base&, Base&)`, if that's a thing that exists and does something special. It will invoke `std::swap<Derived>` and use move constructors/assignment.

So, additionally write, within the declaration of `Derived`:

```
friend void swap(Derived& d1, Derived& d2) {
    d1.swap(d2);
}
```

or just write that one:

```
friend void swap(Derived& d1, Derived& d2) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(static_cast<Base&>(d1), static_cast<Base&>(d2));
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I left out the ADL swap for `Derived` because it isn't directly related to the question. But thanks for pointing out.